# Google Play Games / Services signin randomly stops working with resultCode GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_SIGN_IN_FAILED / 10002

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

Recently I was about to implement Google Play Services with Leaderboards and Achievements to an Android app. For some unknown reason, signins randomly stop working - until the app's apk is reinstalled.

1) General Assumptions

The developer console is properly set up, in draft mode, with a tester account registered.

After a fresh installation of the apk, the signin to Games works as expected. Submitting of scores and unlocking of achievements works. The leaderboard and the achievements activities get shown properly.

Short: Everything works as expected - for some time.

2) Problem Description

After a few disconnects (which consist of Games.signOut() + GoogleApiClient instance disconnect()) and reconnects (GoogleApiClient instance connect()), at some point, which seems random in means of app has been closed, app has been restarted, scores and achievements have been submitted and unlocked, the onActivityResult() has a resultCode of 10002 / GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_SIGN_IN_FAILED. I tried to reconstruct when the error appears, but it was basically just that behaviour plus a random element.

After that, no connect(), reconnect() or disconnect() on GoogleApiClient instance including Games.signOut() worked anymore.

Restarting the app, killing the task, clearing the cache and data, trying to login a day later - nothing worked anymore. Just a reinstall of the apk seemed to reset it - for a short duration until the error occurs again.

I tried to investigate logcat. The suspicious part seems to be that here:

```
D/SurfaceFlinger(  155): createSurface for (1 x 1), name=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.account.AccountPickerActivity
I/ActivityManager(  394): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity: +130ms
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 2 to 3
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 3 to 4
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 4 to 5
E/GameAgent(10397): Unable to retrieve application [REMOVED APP ID] from network
E/GameAgent(10397): Application ID [REMOVED APP ID] is not associated with package [REMOVED PACKAGE NAME]. Check the application ID in your manifest.
E/CheckGameplayAcl(15720): Unable to load metadata for game
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 5 to 9
W/SignInActivity(15720): onSignInFailed()...
W/SignInActivity(15720): ==> Returning non-OK result: 10002
I/System.out(16173): onActivityResult: requestCode = 1003, resultCode = 10002 gac: false/false
```

The System.out is a debug message of the helper's onActivityResult(). gac is the GoogleApiClient instance and false/false stands for isConnected() and isConnecting().

To avoid improper assumptions about a wrong developer console setup: After fresh installations, it works for some signups (about five, but it is not a fixed number)!

For that, I show the logcat parts of the working attempts before:

```
D/SurfaceFlinger(  155): createSurface for (1 x 1), name=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.common.account.AccountPickerActivity
I/ActivityManager(  394): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity: +153ms
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 2 to 3
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 3 to 4
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 4 to 5
E/GameAgent(10397): Unable to retrieve application [REMOVED APP ID] from network
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 5 to 6
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 6 to 7
D/SignInActivity(15720): Transition from 7 to 8
I/System.out(16173): onActivityResult: requestCode = 1003, resultCode = -1 gac: false/false
```

To conclude: Something in SignInActivity seems to fail around transition 4 or 5 when GameAgent is randomly claiming "Application ID [REMOVED APP ID] is not associated with package [PACKAGE NAME REMOVED].".

Sadly, I can't find their sources to investigate more, so I have to ask if anybody else has an idea how to solve it. In the current state, it is not working if users are locked out forever, obviously.

I'm using the latest Google Play Services library.

3) Code Structure

After reading through the documentation, there were the ways of using BaseGameUtils, of GameHelper as an intermediate solution or of pure GoogleApiClient. Sure thing, GoogleApiClient will be the way.

I made a helper class, programmatically structured like the documentation recommends.

It gets instantiated in the Activity's onCreate. Forwarded to it are onStart, onStop, onSaveInstanceState and onActivityResult.

Its constructor uses GoogleApiClient.Builder with Games.API and Games.SCOPE_GAMES.

The helper also implements ConnectionCallbacks and OnConnectionFailedListener while the Builder uses it for both listeners.

The onConnectionFailed method handles a state variable of "isErrorBeingHandled" like recommended in the documentation, temporarily saved in onSaveInstanceState().

If the ConnectionResult is true on hasResolution(), its startResolutionForResult() will get called, else GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog() will get called.

The helper's onActivityResult(), if requestCode is either of the resolution or the error dialog, on an Activity.RESULT_OK will call connect() on the GoogleApiClient instance, on another result will do nothing (also tried connect and disconnect on GoogleApiClient instance, including Games.signOut()).

4) Thank you!

**Update**

I tried publishing the Google Play Services for the app (leaderboards, achievements etc.). Like magically, the error 10002 disappears and signin is possible with a once blocked account again. Currently I will test if that keeps on working.

The error from my current understanding occurs only if the following points are given:

1. unpublished or once published and now unpublished Google Play Services
2. test account registered
3. fresh apk install
4. random fiddling with connect, disconnect/signout, submit score, unlock achievement, show leaderboard, show achievements
5. works for some time
6. blocking after some random time without the chance to ever log in again with resultCode 10002
7. unblock only possible if apk gets freshly installed or Google Play Services get published

My theory is that some caching in the Google Play Services framework does not work properly and it only gets reset if the apk is reinstalled or it gets in a proper state when Google Play Services get published.

Comment: Why do you ask a question and than just disappear? Read these answers, and than comment your opinions and mark as solution if it works to help other programmers (like me) find out the real answer as soon as possible. This is not stackoverflow.com works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the versionCode in my AndroidManifest was different than the version number of my APK in Google play Developer Console. After uploading my new APK to Google play Developer Console, the 10002 problem seems to disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This error is often a config error, like the timestamp issue Henry mentions.  The other case when this happens is when your AndroidManifest.xml does not have the correct app id (it needs to be the 10+ digit number in the google play listing (not the apk listing) in the dev console.

The Android line looks like

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="12345678912" />
```

FWIW, I usually do it template style, have value="@string/app_id" and define that string in resources, but the raw value should work too.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

you are signing to the app with the wrong account.

**long story**

In my case I had 3 different accounts on my phone and I was trying to sign in (implicitly) from the wrong account. How can be a wrong account you might ask? So, basically the app is in the beginning in a "test mode" with only specific accounts that is listed in the Developer Console can access the api. So, what I did is I went to the Google Play Games app, and changed the settings that the account that can sign in is selected.

Comment: BTW you can add more accounts to the Dev Console.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is pretty old now, but I found a helpful post [here](http://www.geekhole.uk/?p=150) which pegs the issue as possibly being because the Google Developer Console project was created from the using the old version of the Google API Console.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I tried to upload by dev apk to the google dev console it gave me an error that my SHA wasn't a match. It shows you the two SHA's. Add the SHA used for the dev build to your firebase project settings under the Android App.

Once you do that you won't need to upload the apk to the dev console at all, I was only doing that as it was suggested in another answer.